# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre un contenedor y una máquina virtual?

Tags: docker, virtualización

La pregunta me surgió viendo [la definición de Docker en wikipedia en su artículo en inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)). La siguiente frase me llamó la atención:

> All containers are run by a single operating system kernel and are
>   thus more lightweight than virtual machines.

que traducido es:

> Todos los contenedores son ejecutados por un único kernel de sistema operativo y por tanto son más ligeros que las máquinas virtuales.

Antes pensaba que eran lo mismo, pero en la frase se aprecia que se hace una distinción.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Una máquina virtual proporciona un *hardware* virtual, por así decirlo. Es decir, cuando creas una máquina virtual es como si hubieras construido un PC "por componentes", eligiendo cuánta RAM ponerle, cuánto disco duro, etc. Todos los elementos de ese "PC" son virtuales en el sentido de que no existen realmente sino que se emulan o se toman prestados del anfitrión en el que se ejecutan (el disco duro del PC virtual es en realidad un fichero dentro del PC anfitrión, la pantalla del PC virtual es en realidad una ventana dentro del PC anfitrión, etc)

En cierto sentido la máquina virtual es como un emulador, con la distinción de que en realidad la CPU no es emulada, sino que se usan características especiales de la CPU real que permiten ejecutar en ella una CPU virtualizada. Por ello la arquitectura de CPU del PC virtual será la misma que la del PC anfitrión (real).

La máquina virtual viene sin operativo. Tienes que instalarle uno. En principio puedes instalarle cualquier operativo soportado por su arquitectura hardware, sin que el operativo anfitrión tenga nada qué ver. Así en un anfitrión con OSX puedes instalar un operativo Windows o Linux en la máquina virtual. La forma de instalarle el operativo sería la misma que en una máquina real, es decir, arrancar la máquina desde un DVD (virtual) que contenga la instalación, particionar y formatear el disco duro (virtual) e instalar en él el nuevo operativo.

Cuando la máquina virtual arranque, lo hará como lo haría una máquina real, es decir, leyendo el sector de arranque de su disco duro (virtual) y cargando el programa de arranque allí contenido, que proseguirá cargando el resto del operativo contenido en ese disco duro (virtual).

Si en un mismo PC anfitrión (real) creas varias máquinas virtuales, cada una requiere su propia cantidad de RAM reservada, su propio disco duro virtual, etc. Esto hace que el espacio del anfitrión usado por las máquinas virtuales sea la suma de los usados por cada una de ellas. Las máquinas virtuales no comparten nada aún si todas usan el mismo operativo. Cada una tiene su propio proceso de arranque (que puede ser lento) independiente, etc.

Un contenedor es una cosa completamente diferente. El contenedor no es una virtualización del hardware, sino una virtualización (por así decir, realmente es otra cosa) de *todo un kernel* y sus *drivers*. No puedes instalar diferentes kernels en diferentes contenedores, ya que todos ellos usan en realidad el kernel del anfitrión.

El contenedor en realidad es una forma de separar procesos, memoria, interfaces de red y sistemas de archivo usando *espacios de nombres* de modo que cada contenedor sólo pueda "ver" lo que está en su espacio de nombres, y no lo que haya en otros contenedores, pero todos se están ejecutando bajo un mismo operativo que suele ser Linux porque es quien soporta esta separación por espacios de nombres.

Un contenedor se instancia a partir de una imagen, que no contiene el kernel sino sólo el resto de herramientas que el contenedor necesite para funcionar. Cuando se dice que un contenedor tiene "Ubuntu", en realidad no tiene todo ese operativo, sino solo las herramientas que tipicamente se encontrarían en `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib`, la configuración de `/etc` etcétera. No contiene el kernel, ni necesita arrancar, pues usa el kernel del anfitrión que ya está arrancado. Su puesta en marcha es mucho más rápida, pues sólo consiste en montar su imagen de modo que sea visible en un espacio de nombres del sistema de archivos y lanzar un proceso (dentro de su espacio de nombres de proceso).

Las imágenes también son más ligeras al no incluir el kernel ni los drivers, ni las utilidades innecesarias, sino tan solo las que el proceso destinado a correr dentro de ese contenedor vaya a necesitar.

Y mejor aún, si lanzas varios contenedores basados en la misma imagen, la imagen está almacenada una sola vez y es compartida por todos ellos, porque es de *solo lectura* (ningún contenedor puede modificar lo que hay en ella). Esto hace que lanzar muchos contenedores sea infinitamente más rápido y "barato" (en términos de los recursos usados) que lanzar máquinas virtuales.

Quizás habría mucho más que contar sobre contenedores y como hacen su "magia", pero sería extremadamente largo. Creo que esta introducción puede servirte para aclararte mejor algunas ideas para cuando continúes leyendo por otros sitios.

**Actualización** Máquinas Virtuales, Contenedores y Cloud.

Mediante lo que se llama Cloud Computing, puedes ejecutar servicios en máquinas que no son tuyas, pagando por ello a los proveedores Cloud como Amazon, Azure o Google entre otros. Un modelo para hacer esto consiste en crear máquinas virtuales, con las características que necesites. El precio se paga por minuto de funcionamiento y depende de las características que le pongas a la máquina virtual. No obstante, es muy infrecuente el andar encendiendo y apagando esa máquina cada minuto. Lo normal, si está dando un servicio continuo, es tenerla permanentemente encendida, con lo que el coste al final viene ser fijo al mes.

Una vez que estás pagando por tener una (o varias) máquinas virtuales en la nube, puedes instalar en ellas docker y usar cada máquina para desplegar varios contenedores. Esto te da mucha flexibilidad para configurar la arquitectura de la aplicación, sin tener que pagar nada extra. El contenedor encaja perfectamente con el modelo arquitectónico de "microservicios".

Otro modelo de despliegue consiste en que tú no tengas que crear las máquinas virtuales, ni instalarles nada, ni gestionarlas, sino simplemente el código que se tendría que ejecutar ante ciertos eventos. Es lo que llaman "Function as a Service". En este caso sólo pagas por el tiempo que la función se esté ejecutando (a nivel de milisegundos). En servidores con muy poco tráfico puede ser más económico que tener tu máquina virtual siempre encendida. La forma en que lo implementan los proveedores cloud "por debajo" es que obviamente hay máquinas virtuales siempre encendidas (por las que tú no pagas en este modelo), sobre las cuales instancian contenedores que son quienes ejecutan tus funciones. Ya que instanciar un contenedor es muy rápido y pueden tener muchos en una misma máquina virtual, al proveedor de cloud le resulta sencillo mantener esos recursos siempre utilizados y cobrar a cada usuario sólo por el tiempo de uso.

Contenedores y Cloud son una pareja indisoluble hoy día.

Comment: No lo habría explicado mejor, una respuesta muy completa. Haría mención también al hecho de que la filosofía de los contenedores se utiliza para el despliegue de aplicaciones en la nube.

Comment: @MarioRuano Gracias. He añadido un anexo sobre cloud,

Comment: @abulafia Entonces,¿se puede decir que un contenedor es un caso muy particular de una máquina virtual, en el sentido en que una mv no tiene por qué tener un instalado un so y un contenedor si lo tiene?

Comment: @Mr.Baldan Puede ayudarte como modelo mental el considerar que un contenedor es como una maquina virtual especial, mucho más rápida de arrancar y más ligera, y que no tiene instalado SO sino que usa el del anfitrión. Como modelo sirve. Pero si quieres ser riguroso, ten siempre claro que ese modelo es en realidad falso. La forma en que se implementa uno y otro no tiene nada qué ver. Un contenedor se parece más a una aplicación que a una máquina virtual, sólo que se ejecuta de forma totalmente aislada de otros, y ese aislamiento lo proporciona el kernel del anfitrión

Comment: @abulafia vale, entonces considero un contenedor como una aplicación y su entorno (por entorno me refiero al kernel y  los drivers) que corre dentro de una máquina virtual.

Comment: @Mr.Baldan Los contenedores sirven sobre todo para resolver el problema de las dependencias. Una aplicación para funcionar necesita no sólo su propio código, sino el de otras bibliotecas, utilidades y llamadas al kernel. El kernel lo proporciona la tecnología de contenedores (y es el del anfitrión), el resto de cosas lo proporciona la imagen de ese contenedor. En una imagen está "empaquetada" la aplicación y todas sus dependencias. Al instanciar esa imagen se pone en marcha la aplicación en un entorno aislado en el que solo puede ver esas dependencias y el kernel anfitrión.

Answer (score 1):

Un contenedor es más ligero, ya que mientras en una máquina virtual necesitas instalarlo un sistema operativo para funcionar y así virtualizar (o eliminan la necesidad de administrar directamente) el hardware del servidor, un contenedor funciona utilizando (virtualizando)  el sistema operativo que tiene la máquina (con Docker instalado) en la que se ejecuta el contenedor.